# Tibco BWContainer won't start service

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I'm trying to run a BW service inside BWContainer. I have started a named container, deployed the service onto the container, but it won't start up. When I start it, I do get some logging, but then it just stops. It doesn't give me any error and it doesn't continue with the log-statement that it has successfully started. In the Tibco administrator, the status of the services goes from "stopped" to "starting" and back to "stopped".

Does anyone have any idea where to look for root causes?

Below is the logging from the application:

```
2014 Mar 04 17:08:40:409 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.9.2, build V19, 2011-5-4
2014 Mar 04 17:08:40:419 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.9.2, build V19, 2011-5-4 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:40:429 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300010 XML Support: TIBCOXML Version 5.51.300.009 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:40:429 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 17.1-b03 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:40:429 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: x86 Windows XP 5.1 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:43:083 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300013 Tibrv string encoding: ISO8859-1 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:43:463 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300022 Engine will be exiting for re-launch within container [c2]. 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:45:446 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.9.2, build V19, 2011-5-4 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:45:476 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.9.2, build V19, 2011-5-4 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:45:496 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300010 XML Support: TIBCOXML Version 5.51.300.009 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:45:496 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 17.1-b03 
2014 Mar 04 17:08:45:496 GMT +1 BW.JMSSnooper-JMSSnooper_Part1 Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: x86 Windows XP 5.1
```

I get the following logging from the BWContainer:

```
Mar 28, 2014 2:01:13 PM com.tibco.bw.container.BWContainer if
INFO: Container <TestContainer> started...
Mar 28, 2014 2:02:04 PM com.tibco.bw.container.BWContainer a
SEVERE: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.tibco.bw.container.BWContainer.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.bw.container.BWContainer.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.bw.container.BWContainer$EngineLoader.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assertion failed.
    at com.tibco.util.Debug.a(Debug.java:276)
    at com.tibco.util.Debug.assertTrue(Debug.java:203)
    at com.tibco.xml.tns.impl.TnsFragmentStoreImpl.initialize(TnsFragmentStoreImpl.java:70)
    at com.tibco.xml.tns.impl.TargetNamespaceCache.<init>(TargetNamespaceCache.java:68)
    at com.tibco.xml.tns.impl.TargetNamespaceCache.<init>(TargetNamespaceCache.java:41)
    at com.tibco.objectrepo.schema.VFileTNSCache.<init>(VFileTNSCache.java:116)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.RepoAgentImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.RepoLoader.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.RepoLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.do(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.connect(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Did you resolve it? What was the reason?

Comment: No, I did not resolve it. I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you have BW (**Designer**), every time you run **designer** the logs are saved at:

1. C:\Users[YOUR NAME].TIBCO\logs\stdout.log
2. C:\Users[YOUR NAME].TIBCO\logs\stderr.log

In the same log(s) folder, it should be a log with the same name as your project. Try the following:

1. Close Designer
2. Open your logs all 3 files
3. Clear the logs
4. Open designer and execute one of your unit test.
5. Go to your package definition and build a new ear.
6. Deploy the new EAR file to your local installation of Administrator. (if you don't have Administrator, EMS and TRA installed on your local machine you are missing components).
7. I Always test locally prior to deploy to a remote server since it is easy to debug.

Any error that takes place should be on one of this logs, you will be able to distinguish is something is not right by looking at these logs

All logs should Populate, if your test pass, and obviously if your service does not start on Administrator it could be because your project deployment {.ear} is not complete or correct.

Make sure all your resources are included when you build your deployment .ear file. Build a new .ear file and deploy to Administrator. Then go to Administrator:

[Your Service Package Name] --> Configuration --> [Your Service Package Name] --> Advanced

Make sure all your global variable information are correct for your server.

If you develop on Windows and deploy to Linux like we do, then you have to be really careful with global variables.
Furthermore if you are using any "Adapters" like ADB Adapter or SAP Adapter, make sure your Administrator (Server Installation also) has the correct settings so it can access the databases.

I will check here daily so we can have this issue resolve for you. If it helps, email me the logs.

Comment: Hi Fernando, thanks for your feedback. But let me clarify some things. The code works fine in designer. The EAR file is correctly built and works fine when deployed by administrator to either local machine or a remote machine. However, running the application using BWContainer, it refuses to start up. I tried it on 2 different machines. I even created a small and trivial project that has *no* dependancies and still it won't run in BWContainer. I have discovered that BWContainer is deprecated in favor of BWEngine, but this requires a whole AMX setup which I don't have.

Comment: Pascal, when you run your project on BW Designer it is actually running on the BWEngine that is why it is working on designer. do you know if they have installed the same version you have on your dev-box of Active Matrix Business Works in the server? Could you tell me which version of BW and Administrator do you have installed? I may be able to replicate your setup and help you further.

Comment: The versions on my dev station and on the server are the same. They are BW 5.9.2 and Administrator 5.7

Comment: Pascal, sorry I do not have that version, we are using BW 5.11 and Admin 5.8. If there is any way you could update your TIBCO Stack I will recommend to do so. Sorry I can not help.

Comment: Thanks Fernando. I can't update right now, but maybe in a few months. I don't believe that will fix the problem though. Have you been able to succesfully do on your environment what I'm not able to do on mine?

Comment: I have not. I don't have access to that version of Administrator.